# Do we really need a tag for every error code?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There are at least <strike>113</strike> 208 tags on Stack Overflow which are compiler or database error code. Except <strike>[`[mysql-error-1064]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1064)</strike>for 26 of the 208, all of them are used less than 20 times.

I believe those <strike>112</strike> 207 error codes do not deserve specific tags. They should be synonym-ed and/or merged into more general tags, or just remove all of them.

---

1. Visual C++ compiler error (`c\d{4}`):

   | TagName | Oct 2010 Count | Feb 2012 Count |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | [c1001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c1001) | 8 | 10 |
   | [c2064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c2064) | 1 | 0 |
   | [c2079](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c2079) | 1 | 2 |
   | [c2662](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c2662) | 1 | 0 |
   | [c2664](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c2664) | 3 | 9 |
   | [c6284](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c6284) | 1 | 0 |
2. C# / VB.NET compiler error (`ca\d{4}`):

   | TagName | Oct 2010 Count | Feb 2012 Count |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | [ca1001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca1001) | 2 | 2 |
   | [ca1026](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca1026) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ca1033](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca1033) |  | 1 |
   | [ca1062](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca1062) | 3 | 5 |
   | [ca1704](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca1704) |  | 1 |
   | [ca1806](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca1806) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ca1811](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca1811) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ca2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca2000) | 2 | 8 |
   | [ca2123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca2123) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ca2202](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca2202) | 2 | 4 |
   | [ca2204](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca2204) | 1 | 0 |
3. Visual C++ linker error (`lnk\d{4}`):

   | TagName | Oct 2010 Count | Feb 2012 Count |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | [lnk2001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lnk2001) | 5 | 16 |
   | [lnk2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lnk2005) | 5 | 20 |
   | [lnk2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lnk2019) | 14 | 53 |
   | [lnk2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lnk2022) | 2 | 3 |
4. MySQL error (`mysql-error-\d{4}`):

   | TagName | Oct 2010 Count | Feb 2012 Count |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | [mysql-error-1005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1005) | 5 | 85 |
   | [mysql-error-1007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1007) |  | 3 |
   | [mysql-error-1008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1008) |  | 2 |
   | [mysql-error-1010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1010) |  | 2 |
   | [mysql-error-1025](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1025) | 4 | 25 |
   | [mysql-error-1030](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1030) |  | 3 |
   | [mysql-error-1040](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1040) | 1 | 5 |
   | [mysql-error-1044](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1044) |  | 17 |
   | [mysql-error-1045](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1045) | 4 | 109 |
   | [mysql-error-1046](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1046) |  | 7 |
   | [mysql-error-1049](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1049) |  | 10 |
   | [mysql-error-1050](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1050) | 3 | 7 |
   | [mysql-error-1051](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1051) | 2 | 2 |
   | [mysql-error-1052](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1052) |  | 23 |
   | [mysql-error-1054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1054) | 18 | 139 |
   | [mysql-error-1060](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1060) | 1 | 5 |
   | [mysql-error-1062](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1062) | 7 | 68 |
   | [mysql-error-1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1064) | 123 | 415 |
   | [mysql-error-1065](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1065) |  | 3 |
   | [mysql-error-1066](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1066) | 3 | 10 |
   | [mysql-error-1067](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1067) |  | 21 |
   | [mysql-error-1071](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1071) |  | 6 |
   | [mysql-error-1075](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1075) |  | 12 |
   | [mysql-error-1091](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1091) |  | 4 |
   | [mysql-error-1093](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1093) | 3 | 53 |
   | [mysql-error-1111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1111) | 5 | 45 |
   | [mysql-error-1130](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1130) |  | 10 |
   | [mysql-error-1136](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1136) | 1 | 3 |
   | [mysql-error-1140](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1140) |  | 3 |
   | [mysql-error-1142](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1142) |  | 17 |
   | [mysql-error-1146](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1146) | 2 | 44 |
   | [mysql-error-1153](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1153) |  | 1 |
   | [mysql-error-1170](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1170) |  | 13 |
   | [mysql-error-1191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1191) | 1 | 0 |
   | [mysql-error-1193](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1193) |  | 2 |
   | [mysql-error-1194](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1194) | 1 | 0 |
   | [mysql-error-1214](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1214) |  | 3 |
   | [mysql-error-1221](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1221) |  | 6 |
   | [mysql-error-1222](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1222) |  | 2 |
   | [mysql-error-1235](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1235) |  | 6 |
   | [mysql-error-1241](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1241) |  | 5 |
   | [mysql-error-1242](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1242) | 2 | 41 |
   | [mysql-error-1248](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1248) | 6 | 7 |
   | [mysql-error-1251](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1251) | 2 | 0 |
   | [mysql-error-1253](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1253) | 1 | 0 |
   | [mysql-error-126](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-126) | 11 |  |
   | [mysql-error-1264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1264) | 2 | 3 |
   | [mysql-error-1292](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1292) |  | 3 |
   | [mysql-error-1305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1305) | 1 | 0 |
   | [mysql-error-1312](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1312) |  | 7 |
   | [mysql-error-1327](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1327) | 2 | 2 |
   | [mysql-error-1329](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1329) | 1 | 0 |
   | [mysql-error-1349](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1349) |  | 3 |
   | [mysql-error-1364](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1364) |  | 4 |
   | [mysql-error-1366](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1366) |  | 2 |
   | [mysql-error-1415](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1415) |  | 2 |
   | [mysql-error-1416](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1416) |  | 3 |
   | [mysql-error-1419](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1419) | 1 | 0 |
   | [mysql-error-1442](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1442) |  | 9 |
   | [mysql-error-1451](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1451) |  | 9 |
   | [mysql-error-1452](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1452) | 1 | 9 |
   | [mysql-error-1628](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1628) | 1 | 0 |
   | [mysql-error-1630](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1630) | 1 | 2 |
   | [mysql-error-2002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-2002) |  | 18 |
   | [mysql-error-2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-2003) |  | 19 |
   | [mysql-error-2006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-2006) |  | 9 |
   | [mysql-error-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-2013) |  | 4 |
5. Oracle DB error (`(?:ora|pls)-\d{4,5}`):

   | TagName | Oct 2010 Count | Feb 2012 Count |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | [ora-00001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00001) |  | 35 |
   | [ora-00018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00018) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-00054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00054) | 1 | 10 |
   | [ora-00257](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00257) |  | 4 |
   | [ora-00600](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00600) | 1 | 11 |
   | [ora-00604](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00604) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-00900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00900) | 3 | 19 |
   | [ora-00904](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00904) | 7 | 72 |
   | [ora-00905](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00905) | 1 | 10 |
   | [ora-00907](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00907) | 2 | 30 |
   | [ora-00911](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00911) | 3 | 19 |
   | [ora-00917](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00917) |  | 3 |
   | [ora-00918](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00918) |  | 13 |
   | [ora-00920](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00920) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-00923](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00923) | 1 | 16 |
   | [ora-00928](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00928) |  | 8 |
   | [ora-00932](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00932) | 1 | 36 |
   | [ora-00933](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00933) | 6 | 50 |
   | [ora-00934](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00934) |  | 3 |
   | [ora-00936](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00936) | 1 | 16 |
   | [ora-00937](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00937) | 3 | 10 |
   | [ora-00942](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00942) | 3 | 56 |
   | [ora-00955](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00955) |  | 7 |
   | [ora-00969](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00969) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-00972](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00972) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-00979](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00979) | 1 | 21 |
   | [ora-00984](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00984) | 1 | 5 |
   | [ora-00997](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00997) |  | 4 |
   | [ora-01000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01000) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-01001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01001) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-01008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01008) | 2 | 7 |
   | [ora-01017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01017) |  | 15 |
   | [ora-01031](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01031) | 3 | 6 |
   | [ora-01034](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01034) | 1 | 5 |
   | [ora-01036](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01036) | 2 | 6 |
   | [ora-01045](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01045) | 2 | 2 |
   | [ora-01086](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01086) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-01400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01400) |  | 20 |
   | [ora-01403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01403) |  | 5 |
   | [ora-01422](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01422) | 1 | 2 |
   | [ora-01426](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01426) |  | 5 |
   | [ora-01427](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01427) | 2 | 7 |
   | [ora-01438](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01438) | 1 | 5 |
   | [ora-01460](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01460) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-01461](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01461) | 1 | 7 |
   | [ora-01555](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01555) | 2 | 2 |
   | [ora-01652](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01652) |  | 3 |
   | [ora-01704](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01704) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-01722](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01722) | 4 | 52 |
   | [ora-01733](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01733) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-01735](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01735) |  | 2 |
   | [ora-01747](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01747) | 2 | 3 |
   | [ora-01790](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01790) | 2 | 3 |
   | [ora-01805](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01805) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-01830](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01830) | 1 | 6 |
   | [ora-01843](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01843) | 3 | 4 |
   | [ora-01858](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01858) |  | 10 |
   | [ora-01861](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-01861) | 4 | 7 |
   | [ora-02014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-02014) | 3 | 4 |
   | [ora-02049](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-02049) | 2 | 2 |
   | [ora-02251](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-02251) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-02289](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-02289) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-02290](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-02290) |  | 2 |
   | [ora-02291](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-02291) |  | 2 |
   | [ora-02391](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-02391) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-03113](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-03113) | 2 | 5 |
   | [ora-03114](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-03114) |  | 6 |
   | [ora-03115](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-03115) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-03135](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-03135) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-04028](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-04028) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-04044](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-04044) | 1 | 3 |
   | [ora-04061](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-04061) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-04063](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-04063) |  | 2 |
   | [ora-04068](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-04068) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-04088](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-04088) |  | 7 |
   | [ora-04091](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-04091) | 4 | 12 |
   | [ora-04098](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-04098) | 2 | 2 |
   | [ora-06502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-06502) | 2 | 8 |
   | [ora-06512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-06512) |  | 22 |
   | [ora-06550](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-06550) | 4 | 36 |
   | [ora-06592](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-06592) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-08177](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-08177) | 3 | 4 |
   | [ora-12012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12012) |  | 3 |
   | [ora-12154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12154) | 6 | 13 |
   | [ora-12514](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12514) |  | 15 |
   | [ora-12519](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12519) |  | 8 |
   | [ora-12541](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12541) | 3 | 9 |
   | [ora-12545](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12545) |  | 5 |
   | [ora-12546](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12546) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-12560](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12560) |  | 19 |
   | [ora-12571](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12571) | 2 | 2 |
   | [ora-12705](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12705) |  | 8 |
   | [ora-12899](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-12899) |  | 10 |
   | [ora-14048](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-14048) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-14758](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-14758) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-17004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-17004) |  | 7 |
   | [ora-20000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-20000) |  | 3 |
   | [ora-20999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-20999) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-21700](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-21700) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-22285](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-22285) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-22324](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-22324) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-22804](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-22804) |  | 2 |
   | [ora-23401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-23401) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-24338](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-24338) | 3 | 5 |
   | [ora-2460](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-2460) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-27101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-27101) | 1 | 2 |
   | [ora-28002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-28002) |  | 5 |
   | [ora-29270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-29270) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-29279](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-29279) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-29280](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-29280) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-29283](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-29283) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-29532](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-29532) |  | 2 |
   | [ora-29861](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-29861) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-29954](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-29954) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-30076](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-30076) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-30373](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-30373) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-30926](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-30926) | 1 | 0 |
   | [ora-31011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-31011) |  | 2 |
   | [ora-32411](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-32411) |  | 1 |
   | [ora-38104](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-38104) |  | 2 |

Comment: Remember, all single-use tags are [automatically removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) in six months.  I think it would be fair to separate them from the others and consider whether the "established" tags should be kept.

Comment: @Roger: There are still [56 such tags](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/12053/).

Comment: Cutting it in half, from 112, makes it look much less severe! Though in general I'm on the side of less tag proliferation.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66624/please-remove-the-error-tag-from-stackoverflow

Comment: See [MSO 75089](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75089/are-ora-01234-tags-too-specific-to-be-useful) for evidence of the ora-01234 tags reappearing.

Comment: And there are more and more :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83877/is-it-allowed-to-create-too-localized-tags.

Comment: They're growing: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61547/oracle-error-tags http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61552/msvc-error-tags

Comment: Yes, we need them to differentiate between different errors.   Some users not tagging it properly isn't a good enough reason to m remove tags

Answer (score 20):

Being responsible for most of that tagging, it shouldn't really come as a surprise that I would speak in favor of keeping the tags.  Speaking to the OPs rationale for why to remove the tags:

> ...all of them are used less than 20 times.

Speaking to the SQL related error codes, SQL related questions are a far less percentage of traffic than Java or .NET, so I wouldn't expect numbers to be as high for sake of the reality that there simply aren't as many people active in the SQL related tags.

Additionally, few (especially the new accounts) are correctly tagging.  Sometimes, it's like pulling teeth to get the error message--let alone the error code--in order to accurately help someone.  This just compounds your issue with usage, but I don't expect people to instantly be aware of community practice and etiquette.

> I believe those 112 error codes do not deserve specific tags. They should be synonym-ed and/or merged into more general tags.

Each error code regards a *specific* error.
The sheer *number* of tags does not give any weight to your argument when they individually signify a uniquely identifiable issue with a respective technology.  Homogenizing the tags utterly destroys what value they currently have.

All I'm reading amounts to "ZOMG - there's esoteric tags!  They should be removed because there's over 100 of them, and many *currently* have under 20 questions associated..."

### For your consideration

[nullpointerexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullpointerexception) is related to ~200 questions--should it, and any other Java/etc related specific error tag be removed from the SO tags?

### Disclosure

I'm not in it for the badge--tagging the ORA error/etc helps me to know what I'm walking into.  In theory, it should help the community to be able to look at existing questions based on the error code to see if there's something similar so the issue can be solved without resorting to an extremely similar question.  SO/etc has wanted that when you google an issue, that an SO/etc comes up high in the search ranks--if you google for a specific ORA error, that currently doesn't happen but you'll see that there are sites that house little more than the error code, the message, and basic instructions for how to address the issue.  That alone is enough reason to me to keep the tags...

### Conclusion

I wish there was more to address, but based on the points of contention raised--I have a hard time believing the question was justified based on the criteria.  If it's worth pursuing, I think it needs to be reconsidered and proposed with a valid criteria.  Because as-is, I have a hard time taking the OP seriously.

I appreciate NullUserException alerting me to this question; I don't come here often and inane questions like these reinforce why that is.

Comment: The fact that there are other useful sites that come high in google for an oracle error code, is a good reason not to keep these tags.  SO should not try to replace other sites that already do a good job and are easy to access.

Comment: My main rationale is these error code tags is too specific to be useful. The low use rate is a supplemental reason. Besides, these tags are seldom applied on questions that require them (see my reply to @Rosinate). This makes the tags almost useless for identification.  And even worse, as 56 of these tags are used only 1
times, according to Roger it leads to information loss anyway if we rely on them.  Finally, why we need the tags if we could describe the errors *in the content*?  (I'm fine with deleting those `nullpointerexception` tags too.)

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: By that rationale, SO shouldn't exist because expertsexchange/yahoo/egghead/etc links already exist...

Comment: @KennyTM: Rather than focusing on the existence of the tag, **read** the questions.  You'd find most can be summed up as "I'm getting this error, here's my code--pls fix it".   They **aren't** specific enough to include the actual message, if the error code at all.  I'm often updating after I've googled based on the little info provided.  And I find the idea of the tags being "too specific" again leads me to question if you actually read the content.  Oracle errors are notoriously cryptic; a syntax error could be *anything*.  To me, your proposition erodes the value of SO--not increase it.

Comment: @OMG: Did you understand my last sentence? How is adding a tag `[ora-00054]` different from adding the term "ORA-00054" in the content of question? And what if there are multiple errors? ( [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1554389/) should be tagged [ora-00600], [ora-06544], [ora-06553] together?) In my mind, SO's tag system isn't for specific tagging, and a tag for every error code is impractical.  Also, this discussion is on tags, of course I'm focusing on tags. If the question is bad, **edit and improve it**. It is not a reason to spawn 100 tags :).

Comment: @KennyTM: You've yet to demonstrate *why* a tag for each code is "impractical".  **Where's the burden you're hoping to alleviate?**  Editting questions is a fine line--misintrepretation can have consequences.  I edit for English readability only, but otherwise use tags to communicate issues to preserve as much of the OPs intent as possible.

Comment: @OMG: It creates too many underused tags, and doesn't work well for categorization. (Plus, what if there are >5 relevant error codes in the question?)

Comment: @KennyTM: I've already pointed out how weak your decision of "underused" is, and you've backtracked on that notion when you agreed that [nullpointerexception] should also be removed though it has 200 associations.  Now you want to suppose that there are five or more error codes--I've only ever seen two at most, and I suggest the OP start a new question rather than blend what are separate issues.  You consistently and spectacularly fail to substantiate the issue you raised--now you delve in to corner cases rather than address core issues?  You're crossing the line into being trollbait...

Comment: I can't see how 'underused tags' is a bad thing. If anything, the question should have the relevant error codes (i.e 'ora-12345') in the tag AND in the question, for increased keyword density. Not sure how many errors a user could be getting at one time.

Answer (score 18):

No.
In my opinion they don't deserve separate tags.

Tags stop being useful (IMO) if there are to many of them. You should both be able to separate things with them as well as group things with them. These are contradictory goals and you have to use your judgement on where to draw the line.

In my opinion a tag for `any and all compiler/linker error` is *way* beyond on the wrong side of that line.

<sub>(I'm an avid fan of tag mergers)</sub>

Comment: That's a pretty short answer. Why do they deserve to stay separate? (I'm not arguing with you, I actually don't know if this is a good idea or not.)

Comment: @Popular - My *NO* is an answer to the question in the title. So I think you have my opinion backwards.

Comment: that's exactly how I interpreted your original answer. I still don't know _why_ you think we don't need separate tags, though.

Comment: @Popular - Well yo wrote *Why do they deserve to stay separate?* in your comment to me. Did you misplace a negative somewhere :-)

Comment: absolutely correct! I meant "don't." I actually had to look at it twice just now, my brain was so convinced that I wrote "don't" initially that I was still seeing it that way.

Answer (score 17):

It doesn't really matter to me if they stay or go, but what I *do* frown upon is the bias against lower-frequency tags.  Their low frequency is largely because people don't tag properly, especially the sorts of people who sign up just to say "plz hlp wt my errorz."

The `[error]` and `[exception]` tags are worse than useless.  You *might* be able to argue that they're useful to warn experienced users of an impending sinkhole question accompanied by walls of code and broken English, but every so often they're actually used legitimately (i.e. by somebody asking about exceptions from a general perspective).  So *merging* all of these tags is **not** going to be helpful to anyone.

If you want to *remove* those tags then you should remove *all* specific-error/exception tags, and that's going to be a Sisyphean task.  Type `exception` into the tag search box and see how many pop up (it'll only show you 50, but the alphabetized results stop at the letter *i*).  None of these tags are inherently more *useful* than any other error/exception tag; some are just more *popular*.

I would have to argue that tags like `[nullpointerexception]`, `[nullreferenceexception]`, and `[invalidoperationexception]` are significantly *worse* than any of the tags mentioned by Kenny above; they could literally mean just about *anything*, and tell you nothing about the question except for the fact that it was probably submitted by somebody who doesn't know how to debug a program.

So please don't zap error tags *just because* they're low frequency, because that's not a meaningful indicator by itself.  If you have a problem with those tags then you should get rid of them *all*.  Personally, I can see them becoming somewhat useful over time on account of the "related questions" feature which, IIRC, looks mainly at the tags.

Comment: +1: My only issue with decisions based on frequency is that the size of the community participating on that tag needs to be considered.  But KennyTM appears to be ignoring the fact that the SQL error codes are more specific than nullpointer/etc...

Comment: @OMG: When did I say `[nullpointerexception]` etc are good? Please don't put words into my mouth. @Aarobot: How is it more Sisyphean than removing `[subjective]` and friends :) ?

Comment: @KennyTM: Zapping and blacklisting one tag is a simple matter for the team.  Removing every single specific-exception/error-related tag would require a significant amount of manual retagging, and unless you want to blacklist *every conceivable error tag* (including ones that haven't been used yet), it's going to be ineffective.

Comment: @Aarobot: Well we had `[newbie]` tag when `[beginner]` was squashed, so it's gonna be a problem. I see your point.

Comment: @KennyTM: You've failed to acknowledge the value of the specific error codes vs the generic exception ones.  That's not "putting words in your mouth", that's pointing out how **little** thought you put into this matter--which was consistently the point of my answer.

Comment: Yes, @Kenny, and perhaps that will turn out to be a Sisyphean task as well.  Doesn't mean we should add another one to our plate. ;)

Answer (score 9):

At least in the [Oracle space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database), those <del>damn</del> codes are very, very, strong organizing principles. People will search by them. Constantly. There are entire sites organized by them. I think that leaving them in their own tags makes sense.

Comment: Except it doesn't work. For instance, [there are 12 posts mentioning `ora-00054`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ora-00054%22) but [only 1 has that tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00054).

Comment: You don't need a tag to be able to search for an error code

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: The tag provides more reliable search results--why am I explaining this on meta?!?

Comment: search engine will also match error code in question itself

Answer (score 9):

I think the real issue is that the tagging system is not intended to be used for specific error messages.  The main purpose of the tagging system is to allow people to

1. Find questions they are interested in answering / qualified to answer.

   - A C# expert will typically filter on [c#] when they want to answer questions.
2. Browse topics they are interested in learning about.

   - If one wants to learn about C#, one would filter on [c#], and add a search term for the specific topic they are interested in.
3. Search for solutions to problems they are having within those topics / technologies.

   - Similar process to number two.  If you have an error, you can search for "`[mysql] error 1005`".  This gets the tag, and searches the body / title for the relevant error.

**I *do not* think that tags should be used to help *ask* one's question**.  If someone is asking a question because they are getting an error back from a MySQL query, they should include that error in the body or title of their question.  I don't think it's likely there are SQL experts browsing the [mysql-error-1055](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1055) tag.  Thus, I don't think that it's useful to have the tag at all.

The same argument can be made for any of the error code tags (including the more popular ones mentioned in other answers, like [nullpointerexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullpointerexception) or [outofmemoryexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outofmemoryexception)).  Without context, none of these tags are useful in helping experts find questions to answer.  They are just duplicate information to what should already be included in the question body or title.

I've updated the original post with current numbers.  Because the community never reached a consensus on this in Oct 2010, the SQL error tags have continued to grow (as well as a couple of others).  Obviously, *I* think it would be a good idea to remove these tags.  I do not think they are helpful, nor are they within the spirit of the tagging system.

Answer (score 4):

What are they hurting?  I vote keep 'em.

Answer (score -1):

No, they should not have their own tags.

However, *this information cannot be lost* because people search for these error codes.

I would suggest that in the retagging process (there are few enough to do by hand), the error code be put into the title of each question if it isn't already there. Question searching and suggestion work strongly off the title, so I think that's the best place to put it.