# Do we really need [keyerror]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[keyerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyerror) seems like a rather useless tag.

The tag info says:

> In languages such as Python and Ruby, a KeyError is a specific
>   exception type that is raised when a key could not be found within a
>   dictionary (mapping). In Python, it is a subclass of LookupError. In
>   Ruby, it is a subclass of IndexError.

Very useful information, indeed.

Comment: Dunno. Do we need [`[keynotfoundexception]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keynotfoundexception)? At least yours has a tag wiki.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, yes, in particular that piece of information about the superclass is extremely valuable. Maybe we should consider adding the favorite color of the developers as well. No really, IMO a tag for a specific error makes no sense. Maybe language agnostic `keyerror` experts will disagree.

Comment: Irony aside, you're right, and the situation is even [worse than that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274616/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code) and has been for a while. There are 1770 questions tagged [`[nullreferenceexception]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullreferenceexception) and **945** questions tagged [**`[mysql-error-1064]`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1064) (*sobs*). Those tags are not going anywhere without serious community effort, and chances are they'll keep coming back if not outright blacklisted.