# Cannot find value in [cannot-find-symbol]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just stumbled upon the [cannot-find-symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cannot-find-symbol) tag. It refers to a common Java compiler error.

We already have a very [comprehensively answered canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean) with 750k views. There are 175 questions tagged with this and it looks like almost all of them could be closed as duplicates of that.

They are often variations on the same theme: a misunderstanding of how imports work, a misunderstanding of how scope works, maybe the odd typo.

The questions under this tag are also quite strongly skewed towards being negatively received. Should we get rid of it?

I would answer 'yes' to all of [Shog9's criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

> - Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
>     and is it unambiguous?
> - Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
> - Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
> - Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

but I'm still not convinced that means that it's useful (well, outside of being used in my ignored tags). What do you think?

Comment: 61 of the 175 questions are closed. That's about 1 in 3. Yet another sign this tag isn't a good one

Comment: @Machavity By that logic surely the whole [tag:java] tag should be nuked ;P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit YES. End my suffering.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure what your point is. Oh, wait, it's [NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) :P

Comment: @Machavity Not sure how best to work out open/closed ratio for a specific tag, but I'm betting for [tag:java] it ain't pretty

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, for Java, [106k are closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+closed%3A1&mixed=0), which isn't bad for a pool of 1.5M questions

Comment: @Machavity Okay, it can stay. (Though don't forget the roomba effect :D)

Comment: @Machavity Maybe there's so much crap that it's impossible to close it fast enough.

Comment: PHP is worse, unsurprisingly! (7.1% closed as opposed to Java's 6.9% - excluding Roomba'd posts of course)

Comment: Obviuosly, if you answered "yes" to all criterias, this tag shouldn't be burninated.

Comment: We had an extensive discussion about error code tags years ago.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274616/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code

Comment: @Sanyash I don't think it is *obvious*. Those criteria were conceived by a human being; they are not infallible.

Comment: Orchestra error: Cannot find cymbal.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Keeps crashing

Comment: another idea to synonymize this to [tag:symbol-not-found]