# Can we export [import-csv]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I recently stumbled across this tag ([import-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-csv)) which has no tag wiki nor usage guidance and only 280 questions under its umbrella.

My main question is ***what is it for?*** which is most naturally followed by ***do we really need it?***

From my short pass on some of the questions tagged, I found that there is actually a PowerShell command [`Import-Csv`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.1) but the tag (as there is no usage guide) is not used exclusively for that. In any other case I don't see a real use for this tag as questions asking about CSVs, even reading (importing?) them can be tagged with [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv) and I believe that will convey the point well enough...

I would say that there are two options to go with this:

- one reasonable thing to do is confine it to the PowerShell function by ***updating the usage guide*** and maybe even ***renaming it*** to the clumsy `powershell-import-csv` or anything more distinctive. Then ***retagging the other questions with `csv`***.
- remove the tag completely and replace all its uses with the more general `csv`. I will submit below my go of the burnination criteria just in case this option will get more support...

***clarification:*** This is not (necessarily) a tag burnination request, rather an open discussion to understand the standing and further actions regarding this tag. The burnination suggestion below is simply brought as another possible option for the community to discuss.

---

***Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?***

No and no. No usage guide nor tag wiki. It is ambiguous in that it might refer to the PowerShell function or to simply reading a csv file with any programming language that supports so.

***Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?***

Well the concept is not really clear, but in general yes - questions about working with csv files are generally on-topic here...

***Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?***

IMO, not at all. In most current uses, it could be easily replaced with [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv), a tag which has >70k questions and >1.5k watchers.

***Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?***

As already discussed, no. In some contexts it means the PowerShell function. In others it's reading csv files. In others it's simply anything related to csv.

Regarding the extra criteria: well, it doesn't so much causes harm as much as it could simply be replaced with a more appropriate tag to get better attention to the question.

Comment: Just to add some info: from the currently tagged questions, there's a high probability that [this PowerShell question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980226) was the origin of the [tag:import-csv] tag (the original revision already had this tag since the beginning). [Questions older than Oct 11 '16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-csv?tab=newest&page=19&pagesize=15) were (probably mis)tagged from later edits. (Of course, there's a possibility that the *real* oldest tagged question got the tag removed...)

Comment: Note that we also have [tag:import-from-csv] and [tag:export-to-csv]. If we think those tags are fine, we can move over all non-PowerShell questions to [tag:import-from-csv], which is not related to any language or function afaict. And, of course, we also have [tag:export-csv] which is in the same boat as [tag:import-csv]

Comment: @ErikA uuf it's worse than I thought... To be honest, I would say that `import-from-csv` is also unnecessary... I feel like it's too specific and questions using that can be just tagged `csv`... I don't think we have tags for `read-from-dict` or `assign-value-to-key-in-dict` - simply tag `dictionary`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo With the current burnination process, if we have an on-topic and unambiguous tag, which the export-to and import-from csv tags are, we have no justification for removing them. While overly specific tags are useless imo, previous discussions have not led to removal of them (see an old discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274616/7296893) for a large collection of error code tags, which are often extremely specific and useless imo but didn't get removed)

Comment: @ErikA You'd have to decide between `import-from-csv` and `import`,`csv` there.

Comment: Related: [Should tags be created for functions of APIs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360271/should-tags-be-created-for-functions-of-apis), [Are random keywords useful as tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209888/167668)

Comment: @DidierL From the second link: *"if I can imagine myself searching for questions to answer using the tag, it's a good tag."* - that almost answers that. I can only imagine someone searching for questions to answer using this tag ***if they were meaning to answer about PS imprt_csv function***...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, I don't know if those 2 questions can be considered as authoritative, but I think they make sense. It looks like using `powershell` + `csv` would be sufficient for people looking for questions to answer on this topic.

Comment: @DidierL Just found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62183419/efficient-way-to-import-multiple-csvs-in-neo4j) tagged with `import-csv` when it was loading a CSV with neo4j ***while there is a tag `load-csv` specific to neo4j***... <face-palm>...

Answer (score 10):

<sub>Converting my comments to an answer...</sub>

`import-csv` is a specific command (set) in PowerShell. The tag being named that is clearly intending it to be used for PowerShell questions about that; any questions that just happen to revolve around *importing data from a CSV file* would be misusing such a tag (I see some questions are even tagged with [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import), [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv), and [import-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-csv), which just screams lazy "tag everything that seems related" behavior.

Uses in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) questions, for example, should be using [read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/read.csv), or [fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fread) with [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv), instead. Python also has a `read_csv` command, apparently, but the [read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/read.csv) tag seems specific to R. Maybe a Python user familiar with that could suggest an edit to that tag's wiki excerpt (or create a `[read_csv]` with an underscore, instead...).

I've updated some questions already that should be using different tags, and I've [added a tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/5048583) for [import-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-csv) that clarifies its use *in PowerShell*.

Whether or not it should be burninated is debatable, but I think it should definitely be cleaned up first.

Comment: Given that no-one actually reads tag descriptions, should we rename it to include "PowerShell" or "PS" in the tag name? Otherwise it'll just be misused forever. Perhaps make a LaTeX/SQL-tag style pop-up when using the tag without PowerShell

Comment: @Adriaan Those pop-ups have never had any intelligence, though, they always pop up even if they're just to make you add a related tag and you've already added one.

Comment: @Adriaan No, I don't think so, unless you're ready to do the same for the rest of the powershell-specific command tags (and all the other language-specific command tags).

Comment: I voted to approve your tag wiki excerpt.  As an aside, I *still* find it incredibly annoying that as someone with editing privileges I cannot unilaterally approve an edit, nor can I make the edit myself since it's locked into "suggested edit" mode until it is approved.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If in the Suggested Edits review queue, you should be able to choose 'Improve Edit' to unilaterally apply the edit and approve mine via Community. Or is that not an option for tag edit suggestions?

Comment: I don't remember if there was an "improve edit" button.  If there was, I'd almost certainly have to add some junk text to make it stick.

Comment: "any questions that just happen to revolve around importing data from a CSV file would be misusing such a tag" Considering the tag had no guidance and/or description, it's hard to blame them. After that it's lazyness indeed.

Comment: @Mast *"Considering the tag had no guidance and/or description, it's hard to blame them"* - as if people read those... I often see questions with tags whose usage guidance is literally `DO NOT USE THIS TAG`...

Comment: @TylerH [a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209888/167668) from the comments above has a nice guideline: ***"if I can imagine myself searching for questions to answer using the tag, it's a good tag"***. This definitely supports your answer as I can only imagine someone searching this tag to answer questions about PowerShell. The usage is now updated, but funny enough currently there are 143 questions tagged `import-csv` ***without*** [powershell] and 107 ***with***… I will try personally to clean some more and hope others will help. All we can do is hope it will not be misused?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I think any tag that is even slightly ambiguous will always be misused, whatever the description of the tag (which people don't read anyway). The sentence you quote is relevant only if the tag is not ambiguous, otherwise it is useless for searching questions to answer based on it.

Comment: @DidierL I completely agree and sadly seen it many times. I think it's one of those things we don't have much control over and can only hope it will prevent *some* users from misusing. In the end, it's not ***that*** active tag...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I think the best control we can have is finding good tag names, and then requesting a rename or doing it manually. Otherwise we are doomed into a neverending retagging story. You are very motivated right now to fix it for that one tag, but will you still be in 2 months, and what about the many other tags with similar issues?

Comment: @DidierL well, I agree with everything you say... What are you suggesting? Renaming in addition?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Renaming or burninating, whatever makes the most sense. If the tag still does not add any meaningful information to the post even after renaming, there is no point keeping it. I don't know what's best – I'd say it would be up to active users on the `powershell` tag to decide.

Comment: @TomerikooYes, I have been making slow in-roads on re-tagging. It's important not to move too fast to avoid flooding the Active pages with old questions... I usually do 3 or 4 at a time.

Comment: @DidierL Neither renaming nor burninating make sense here; tag cleanup is what makes sense. The tag now has a description in the wiki excerpt, which should reduce the misuse going forward. All that's left is to remove the tag from questions not about PowerShell (while performing any other edits such questions might also need at the same time).

Comment: @TylerH This tag name is really too generic and ambiguous to expect that it will be used as you would like it to be used. Many other tags in a similar situation, with a proper description, are currently misused, so I don't see why it would be any different here. Remember that you are about to untag more than half of the questions in this tag! For me it is absolutely not obvious that the purpose of this tag should be the PowerShell command. Putting a dash between words is a common way of creating tags.

Comment: @DidierL It's a command, that it's a common task is not the command's fault. "more than half" isn't particularly meaningful. There are tags with 10 uses and tags with 100000000 uses. A tag used a total of ~250 times is insubstantial. If you think all PS command tags should be prefaced with `powershell-` or `ps-`, that's fine, but that's a different question to ask, not an answer to this question.

Comment: We already have a [tag:import-from-csv] tag for questions about parsing and converting CSV data into a language-specific data structure. I suggest we retag questions tagged [tag:import-csv] but not related to PowerShell with this tag.

Answer (score 7):

### This tag should not exist

This tag is way too ambiguous to hope that people will use it properly, even with a specific description (people don't read them anyway).

Currently, there are

- 231 questions tagged [import-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-csv)
- [108 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-csv+powershell) tagged [import-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-csv) and [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) (less than half)
- [123 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-csv+-powershell) tagged [import-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-csv) without [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) – and previously more, considering that TylerH already started untagging some of them
- [452 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D%20%22Import-Csv%22%20is%3AQ%20-%5Bimport-csv%5D) containing "Import-Csv" and tagged [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) without [import-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-csv) (so they seem to be missing out on this tag, if it should be PowerShell specific)

In all cases, it means that people want to *import csv* files. It just happens that it is also a command name in PowerShell, but the dash is a common separator in tag names, so we cannot assume it will be interpreted like that (and it is not).

We cannot solve the ambiguity through the tag description, however this tag should not be necessary at all:

- non-powershell questions about importing csv files should be good enough with just the [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv) tag (+ probably some language tag)
- PowerShell questions about importing csv files should be good enough with the [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv) and [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) tags combined.

In general, we should not need to create tags for every function in every language. If we really do for specific languages, the tag should be disambiguated by prefixing with the language name. If we want to keep a tag for that usage, it should thus be renamed accordingly.

See also

- [Should tags be created for functions of APIs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360271/should-tags-be-created-for-functions-of-apis)
- [Are random keywords useful as tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209888/167668)

Comment: Those are some good arguments well put... My initial feeling was that this tag is too specific (as I expressed in comments), whether it's for PowerShell, and also too ambiguous for anything else. Sadly, I find it hard to see anything done with this tag like renaming or removing

Comment: Dealing with tag disambiguation is always hard, I'm afraid, and it often involves a lot of manual work. Although here, if we decide to remove it, we could just make it a synonym of [tag:csv] and we would be good.